# navigation hover effect cover up the box shadow from content

Tags: jquery, navigation, css

i will on my navigation with the hover effect to cover up the box shadow from content.

here my testsite:

http://www.behringer-mauch.de/Tischler_Hehmann/index.php

And this is what i want:

[image]

How can to solve this ?

With CSS or jQuery ?

Comment: if you want us to look at your code, you need to show it to us. Just linking to a site won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the box-shadow from your `<div id="content">` and change the box-shadow to this:

```
box-shadow: 0px -7px 16px -6px rgba(70, 48, 25, 0.7), 
            inset 0px -7px 16px -6px rgba(70, 48, 25, 0.7);
```

to `<div id="navigation">`

Comment: @Dave-88 if it was what you're looking for. Please mark as answer so we can close this question. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to remove box-shadow on hover. Here is some code example.

```
li:hover{box-shadow:none;}
```